# Racket: 2htdp Does `read-words/line' preserve last newline information?

Tags: racket

I'm reading [Part two](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html) from the 2htdp book, and I'm curious about the behavior of the `read-words/line` function that lives under `2htdp/batch-io`.

I created two different files, the first file having a `\n` at the end of the file and the second file without it, like this:

```
echo -ne "first line\n\nthird line\n" > file1.txt 
echo -ne "first line\n\nthird line" > file2.txt
```

if I read each one of the files with the `read-words/line`, this is the result:

```
(read-words/line "doc/book/htdp2/data/file1.txt")
  ; => '(("first" "line") () ("third" "line"))

(read-words/line "doc/book/htdp2/data/file2.txt")
  ; => '(("first" "line") () ("third" "line"))
```

It looks that the function isn't preserving the information from the last newline character in the first file.

Is that behavior intended?

I'm Running Dr Racket 6.2.1 on a GNU/Linux box.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say yes. The intention of read-words/line is to produce a list of words for each line read. A line is normally a sequence of characters ending in a newline. The last line of a file can end in "eof-of-file" instead of a newline. If you try this example:

```
echo -ne "first line\n\nthird line\n\n" > file1.txt
```

I expect the last line to produce an empty list of words.

Comment: As you said, this is the intended behavior. I opened a thread in the racket-users forum, and they said this is the intended behavior and it has been added to the documentation.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/racket-users/YnXJ36XGohM